# Android Storing Application Settings Locally

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, optionmenu

We are creating an app where i want to store certain settings locally on the device.

The settings will be

1. Account Settings
2. Notification Settings
3. Help
4. About
5. Logout

I came across this on foursquare and Twitter Application.. when you go thru Options Menu and to Settings like below

[image]
[image]

How can i implement similarly on my application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store such settings use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). This is the most convenient way. You can also add a [PreferencesActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) to make the second screen you posted.

Comment: thank you.. can you refer me to some tutorial so i can learn about it ?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/ and http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences